# Maven Dependencies on Plugin Development

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, pom.xml

Why does the dependencies in pom.xml is not being accepted by the program/plugin?

i have included the JSON dependencies on the pom.xml yet still not working.

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
The import org.json cannot be resolved
```

how to solve this issue?

Comment: When i tried to include the jar file in the build path, i get an error of NoClassDef on json/exception.

Comment: tried to look in other posts still not getting the correct way to solve this issue

Comment: You may want to look at Eclipse Tycho which handles the interface between Eclipse plugins and maven.

Answer (score 1):

The runtime classpath of your plug-in is controlled entirely by the contents of its MANIFEST.MF file. You can use Maven poms to set up the compile time path, but you must include everything you need at runtime in the plug-in manifest, either as a dependency or as something contained in the plug-in itself.